# Curl api call return empty array

Tags: php, json, api, curl

If I make this call with file_get_contents, it is returning the data, but with curl it show error true, code: 204, with all empty arrays, I m making  post of single query string, I am just a novice in programming any help, thanks.
Array ( [error] => 1 [dname_avail] => [domname] => Array ( [tld_code] => )

```
<?php
$json = '';
if(isset($_POST['querystring'])){
$string_sanitised = $_POST['querystring'];
$query_var= str_replace(" ","",$string_sanitised);

// set HTTP header
$headers = array('Content-Type: application/json',);

// *** create the call to the API and pass parameters along
//apikey =xx67676876868686868686

$url = 'http://api.mydomain.com/domlook/domname/'.$query_var.'/apikey/xx67676876868686868686/';

// Open connection
$ch = curl_init();

// Set the url, number of GET vars, GET data
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
// Execute request
$result = curl_exec($ch);

// Close connection

curl_close($ch);
// get the result and parse to JSON
$result_arr = json_decode($result, true);
print_r($result_arr);   
}else{
echo "error";
}

?>
```

Comment: `Content-Type` is a _response_ header, so it makes little sense that you are sending it with your _request_.

Comment: Are you sure it's returning valid json? If you `var_dump( $result )` what does it output?

Comment: var_dump($result) too return empty array

Comment: if i dont pass headers..it shows empty array, when I changed curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers); to curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, 1);, it successfully  return arrays data......but with an error message Warning: curl_setopt(): You must pass either an object or an array with the CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, CURLOPT_QUOTE, CURLOPT_HTTP200ALIASES and CURLOPT_POSTQUOTE arguments in C:\xampp\htdocs\jksjdsjslj.php on line 22